# sh screen - Wait for screen to terminate

Tags: shell, wait, gnu-screen, terminate

I'm writing on a little script that does send a command to a running screen session. This command stops the screen but not instantly. I need to wait for it to finish in order to continue with the rest of the script.

This is how I stop the screen:

```
screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`"
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an solution:

You just simply check if the screen is still running and wait (`sleep`) for one second.

Like this:

```
while screen -list | grep -q $SCREEN_NAME
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the exit code? Trying to parallelize a few tests using screen.

Comment: @LeblancMeneses since you're not really waiting for the screen but rather wait for it to disappear you can't with this method.

Answer (score 0):

For `*nix` systems, you can use the `wait` command in your shell script. `wait` can take a `PID` as well, so you can do `wait $!` to wait on the last executed command run in background. If your commands are not running in background (no `&` at the end of the command), then running your script will wait until that command finishes

Comment: This does not work! The programm just runs through and does not wait for it to end!

Comment: did you try `wait` or `wait $!`?

Comment: try running your script in background: add `&` to the end of the command and use `wait` then. Try that

Comment: The point is that the command ``screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`"`` returns basically instantly. it is just sending the command to the screen and then it goes to the next command not waiting for the screen to terminate. If I put `&` at the end of the command and then use wait this would continue the moment the previous command has send the command to the screen.

Comment: The screen and all the child processes of the screen are not children of the shell that launched them.  Thus `wait` and `wait $!` can't work. `wait` only works for children of the shell, even if you specify a process id to `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

If you reattach the screen session, then it will automatically wait until all the processes within are done.  And if you try to reattach to a session that is already done, it will just error out immediately.

If you want to run in "headless" mode, then BrainStone's answer is good enough. Just be sure to name your session (`$SCREEN_NAME`) uniquely. Something like `SCREEN_NAME=$(date +my_screen_thing_+%H%M%S)` to get a timestamp on it.