# Make systemd wait for a screen to terminate

Tags: wait, systemd, gnu-screen

There is a question ([sh screen - Wait for screen to terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087964/sh-screen-wait-for-screen-to-terminate)) about how to wait for a screen session to terminate before continuing.

The solution uses a loop, but I don't see a possibility to use a loop in systems service scripts.

Currently what I use is:

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S starforge -p 0 -X stuff "stop^M"
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 10
```

Usually, I don't need the whole 10 seconds, but I need some way to know if the screen already terminated